# Pass a parameter from a listbox/button to a function in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Having a horrible time learning Tkinter, and it seems to me as though when you make a button execute a function `...command=do_this)`, that command cannot have any parameters, it can only execute a function.

I would like to pass a parameter to `do_this()` to give it functionality depending on the input, like `do_this(parameter)`. However the command functionality of a button does not use the brackets at the end of the function name and doesn't seem to support parameters.

How do I get around this? The intended use of the program is to generate a frequency histogram based on different groups of data from a csv file, where the groups are selected via a listbox, then the histogram is generated by pressing a button.

Comment: research `lambda` and `functools.partial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the call of your widget, insert
`command=lambda parameter1=value,parameter2=value,etc:name(parameters)`

For example, if u want a button to execute a function do_this(a)
with paramter a set to 5 it's
`command=lambda a=5:do_this(a)`